# Make link in navigation bar open in new window

Tags: magento-1.9

I added page links to my top navigation bar by creating subcategories and creating url rewrites and it's working perfectly.
My question is: How do I make the link open in a new tab or new window?
I have one item in the navigation that is linked to an external site and would like it to open in a new tab rather than take the user away from my site.
Is this possible?
My site's address is http://hi-schoolworld.com/ and the page is titled Life Pics

Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

This would be the proper way to open a Magento XML top link in a new tab:

```
<reference name="root">
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
            <label>New Tab</label>
            <url>http://yoursite.com/newtab</url>
            <title>Retailer Login</title>
            <prepare/>
             <urlParams/>
            <position>2</position>
            **<aParams>class="new-tab" target="_blank"</aParams>**
        </action>
    </reference>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a core Magento question, so it's probably going to get flagged.

Use the 'target' value in your link:

```
<a href="http://www.mycoolsite.com/" target="_blank">Visit my cool site </a>
```

_blank will cause the link to be opened in a new window or tab, depending on the users browser preferences.